# PHP Modify an Array within an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I created an Array and put the Array inside another Array. I would like to now modify the Array, but the code never does modify it.
Here is the Create Part:

```
$arr_row_name = array();
for($nrow=0;$nrow < $numRows;$nrow++)
{
    $arr_slot_name = array();
    for($nsp=0;$nsp < $numServProvider + 1;$nsp++)
    {
        $arr_slot_name[] = "Closed";
    }
    //Add Slot to the row.......
    $arr_row_name[] = $arr_slot_name;
}
```

Here is the part where I try to access the array and modify it.

```
$arr_row_length = count($arr_row_name);
for($x=0;$x<$arr_row_length;$x++)
{
    $arr_slot_name = $arr_row_name[$x];
    $arr_slot_length = count($arr_slot_name);
    for($slot=0;$slot<$arr_slot_length;$slot++)
    {
        $arr_slot_name[$slot] = "Open";
    }           
}
```

Comment: how about `$arr_row_name[$x][$slot] = "Open";`

Comment: They say you may get unexpected results if you modify an array while traversing it. It might be better to make a copy of the array. Then, while traversing the original, you alter the copy. Then you overwrite the original with the copy.

Answer (score 1):

In your second bit of code, change:

```
$arr_slot_name = $arr_row_name[$x];
```

to:

```
$arr_slot_name = &$arr_row_name[$x];
```

The way that you have it, you are making a copy of `$arr_row_name[$x]` into `$arr_slot_name` ... in the second option, you are assigning it by reference and will be able to change the original ...

Comment: Ah. I know I was missing something. Thank you.